# Can't read .csv file line by line

Tags: c++, visual-studio, csv, fstream

i'm trying to read a .csv file line by line

this is my code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream fname;
    fname.open("Inc_001.csv");
    if (!fname) { cerr << "Error" << endl; return 1; }
    string x, y;
    while (fname.good()) {
        getline(fname, x, ';');
        getline(fname, y, '\n');

        cout << x << y;
    }
    fname.close();

    return 0;
}
```

and this is my .csv file

```
0;0 
0.1;0.01 
0.2;0.04 
0.3;0.09 
0.5;0.25 
0.7;0.49 
1;1
```

But everytime i run the code, the output is "Error" and i don't know what's the problem to fix

[This is a screenshot of my solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYEgQ.png)

Comment: Please don't use screenshots of error messages, copy'n'paste them inline in your question. This makes these errors easier to search for (which you did, right?) and also makes them accessible to visually impaired people. BTW: You never verify that the `getline()` calls succeed. That said, as a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: What's the error message? The code seems to work fine on my pc, with a sample CSV file provided by you.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you always get that `Error` message is because `ifstream::open` wasn't able to open the file at the path you indicated.

Looking at your screenshot, it looks like you placed the CSV file at the root directory of your solution, categorized in a filter named `Source`.

You could change the `Output` directory in which your executable file has to be placed by changing the location in `Project > <your_project> Properties... > Linker > General > Output File` and then placing the CSV file in the configured folder.

Or you could place your CSV file in the default target directory, which should be in the form of `<your_solution_name>\Debug\...`, where the compiled binary is located.

Answer (score 0):

```
float num1, num2;
char c;

if (myfile.is_open())
{
    while ( myfile >> num1 >> c >> num2 )
    {
        cout <<  << num1 << "," << num2;

    }
    myfile.close();
}
```

Comment: You do not need the "if" and you do not need the close . . .

Comment: Add some context by explaining how your answer solve the problem in question, instead of posting code-only answer.